# Получить embedded resource файл

Tags: c#, .net

Как добраться до ресурса который лежит например в `folder1/folder2/folder3/res.data`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var streamName = "AppDefaultNamespace.folder1.folder2.folder3.res.data";
using (var stream = this.GetType().Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(streamName))
{

}
```

Если не уверены насчет имени - список всех ресурсов можно проверить в отладке вызовом `this.GetType().Assembly.GetManifestResourceNames(streamName)`.

Answer (score 1):

Вам не должно хотеться пользоваться низкоуровневыми средствами доступа к ресурсам.

Если вы пишете приложение командной строки или WinForms, вы должны просто положить данные в `.resx`, и обращаться к ним через `Properties.Resources.ИмяВашегоРесурса`. ([Документация.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7k989cfy%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)) В крайнем случае, если вам нужно динамически менять ресурсы, вы можете [использовать `ResourceManager`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f45fce5x.aspx).

Если вы пользуетесь WPF, вы должны положить файл как Resource (а не embedded resource), и использовать [pack URI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/aa970069%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

---

Может быть, вы пробовали сделать правильно, но у вас не получилось? Или вы не нашли [правильный инструмент для вашей задачи](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/709/10105)? Расскажите, для чего вам нужен доступ к ресурсам и как вы их используете.